# Can I plot a particular fit with geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is some sample data I am working with

```
my.data <-tibble::tribble(
               ~Mean,          ~Variance,
    9.16666666666667,   16.2269503546099,
    1.91666666666667,   4.88652482269504,
              2.4375,   6.03856382978723,
    4.35416666666667,   14.3187056737589,
    2.20833333333333,   4.97695035460993,
   0.458333333333333,   1.01950354609929,
    1.70454545454545,   6.11997885835095,
   0.568181818181818,   1.18128964059197,
   0.431818181818182,   1.27431289640592,
   0.340909090909091,  0.462473572938689,
  0.0454545454545455, 0.0909090909090909,
   0.113636363636364,  0.242600422832981
  )
```

I'd like to plot a polynomial with particular coefficients `c(1,/1.46)` using `geom_smooth`. I thought I could do something like

```
my.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Mean,Variance)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_abline() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, color = 'black', linetype = 'dashed', size= 0.5, 
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, coefs = c(1, theta))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

But the `geom_smooth` does not appear in the plot.  Why is that?  Can I plot polynomials with arbitrary coefficients using geom_smooth()?

Comment: If I were you I would remove `geom_abline()` and, in `geom_smooth`, remove `coefs = c(1, theta)`. Try it.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "polynomial with particular coefficients". For `poly`, the `coefs=` argument should be a named list with the "centering and normalization constants used in constructing the orthogonal polynomials". Do you mean something like: you fit a curve `y=0+1*x+1/1.46*x^2` and you want to plot that?

Comment: Dont use `geom_smooth` because you're really not modeling anything. Try `stat_function` instead. It's not clear to me exactly what you're doing with `poly()` and those coefficients. What line exactly are you trying to plot? `x + 1.46*x^2`?